# why does it give me bigger than 4 always?

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the numbers bigger than 4 after I loop in every other number, but the problem is that it keeps giving me **bigger than** 4 even tho the number isn't bigger than 4. thank you!

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
bool isvalidcc(const string& s)
{

    vector<char> v (s.begin(), s.end());
    for(auto i=0 ; i<v.size();i+=2)
    {

        if (v.at(i)>'4')
        {
            cout<<v.at(i)<<"bigger than 4"<<endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<v.at(i)<<"smaller than 4"<<endl;

        }

    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{

    vector<string> cardnumbers = {
         "371449635398431"
    };

    int i;
    vector<string>::iterator itr;

    for (i = 1, itr = cardnumbers.begin(); itr != cardnumbers.end(); ++itr, i++) {
//        cout   << i << " "
//              << *itr
        ((isvalidcc(*itr)));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `'4'` is differen to `4`

Comment: ohhhh, that's because it's char correct? @M.M ! THANKS

Comment: Your code does not compile - figure that out first.

Comment: It does compile on my end tho!!  @TedLyngmo

Comment: It didn't follow the C++ standard before your latest edit.

Comment: and cardnumbers is not really a vector of digits, its just a vector containg one string

Comment: @pm100, yeah i know but inside the loop i am splitting them into digits! is there something wrong with that ?

Comment: Now your code does not match your question, which makes this at best confusing for the next person with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

Because v.at(i) is a char instead of an int it converts it into ascii code.
this means u have to convert the char in to an int the right way.

```
if (v.at(i) - '0' >4)
```

the - '0' will convert it to an int the right way otherwise it will return the wrong values, u can check this by making a new int variable and cout <<

```
int n = v.at(i);
cout << n;
```